# .when Ajax success is done run another function with some jquery, almost working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, .when

After a submit event runs with prevent default (to avoid the submit page refresh) along with some algorithms, the oneStory(id) function is called on success for sending the updated .put data to the node.js API.

At this moment, the fields that were toggled-open (by the jquery below) to be updated, undesirably toggle-closed because the whole html template is refreshed (seemed the best way to give handlebars.js the new db data), but I would like these comment fields to remain in view throughout the update (thus reflecting the realtime update).. *should .live be implemented somewhere?*

Am sure there is a better way to do this realtime update, but thought to have all the stories refresh, and .when done, .then pass the id of the updated comment to jQuery to toggle open the comments section for the particular story that had a comment updated. Right now though, this .then jQuery logs `Object` (of the resJSON) `comments for: Object are open` (instead of the _id)

What's more, with the success call refreshStory(id) from oneStory(id) from the .put AJAX (which does .put because the update is stored in the db), the view appears to have refreshed the content because the console logs everything of the foundAllSuccess function and the story's comments toggle-close, but unless I instead call foundAllSuccess as the actual success call of the refreshStory(id) function, the async repopulation of **content doesn't include the updated comment!?**

```
function oneStory(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories/" + id,
    method:'get',
    success: refreshStory(id), //foundAllSuccess does work here
    error: foundError
  })
}

function refreshStory(id) {

  var thisID = '#' + id;
  console.log(thisID);

  $.when($.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories",
    method:'get',
    success: foundAllSuccess,
    error: foundError

  }).then(function(thisID){

    console.log(thisID);
    $(thisID).parentsUntil( ".comments" ).parent( ".comments" ).slideToggle();
    console.log("comments for: " + thisID + " are open");

  })

)}

function foundAllSuccess(resJSON) {

  var templateSource = $("#storiesTemplate").html();

  console.log('Getting All the Stories..');
  console.log(templateSource);

  var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

  var storiesHTML = template({stories: resJSON});

  $('#allTheStories').html(storiesHTML);

  console.log('Got All of the Stories..');

}
```

Here's the HTML (maybe there's a better way to refrence this too, than the parentUntil.parent)

```
<div class="comments" style="display:none;">
  \{{#each comments}}<div class="comments-frame">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="\{{_id}}" />
```

And the jQuery that accurately toggles open the comments to begin with:

```
$(document).on("click", ".storyTitle", function () {
  var $that = $(this).closest('.story').find('.comments')
  $that.slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

}).then(function(thisID){

```
console.log(thisID);
$(thisID).parentsUntil( ".comments" ).parent( ".comments" ).slideToggle();
console.log("comments for: " + thisID + " are open");
```

})

`thisID` inside this method is NOT as same as the one outside it. Just remove the parameter and you will be fine.